# Receiving modified div innerHtml

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not am experienced asp.net user so hopefully this is fairly easy as it is in php.

I am trying to receive modified html of a div that is modified by the user of a webpage and save it back to a database.

When I click the save button the old(previous) html data is being displayed not the new html data that I want saved.

html:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="saveButton" type="button" CssClass="clickable" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="SaveButtonClicked" />
<div id="formContainer" class="form-container" runat="server">
    <div class="form-header">Form Title</div>
    <ul class="section-sortable"></ul>
    <div class="form-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit form" />
    </div>
</div>
```

c#

```
 protected void SaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              //Returns old html when it should return the new modified html?
               Debug.Write(this.formContainer.InnerHtml); 
            }
```

The html modification code is not shown here but the html is being modified..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only solution I found was to listen to both the Click and ClientClick events copy the Inner HTML from the div to a hidden input control and then the data is visible on the click event.